# Local File Search with iterative algorithm

Tags: java, graph, io, iteration

I am working in a desktop application for windows using Java. In my application, there is a requirement to search all .php. To do this,

here I use **recursive methods**.

```
import java.io.File;

public class Copier {

    public static void find(String source,String rep) {
        File src = new File(rep);
        if (src!= null && src.exists() && src.isDirectory()) {
            String[] tab = src.list();
            if (tab != null) {
                for(String s : tab) {
                    File srcc = new File(rep+"\\"+s);
                    if (srcc.isFile()) {  
                        if (srcc.getName().matches(".*"+source+"$")) {
                            System.out.println(s);
                        }
                    } else {
                        find(source,srcc.getAbsolutePath());
                    }
                }
            } else {
                //System.out.println(" list is null");
            }
        }
    }
```

and here i use **iterative algorithm**  with breadth-first-search with queue but it not work

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.LinkedList;


public class Copier {
public static void find(String source,String rep)
{
    File src=new File(rep);
    LinkedList<File> qu=new LinkedList();
    if(src!=null && src.exists() && src.isDirectory())
    {
        File[] tab=src.listFiles();
        if(tab!=null)
        {
        for(File s:tab)
        {
            qu.addLast(s);
        }
        while(!qu.isEmpty())
        {
            File srcc=qu.getFirst();
            qu.removeFirst();
            if(srcc.isFile())
            {
                if(srcc.getName().matches(".*"+source+"$"))
                    System.out.println(srcc.getName());
            }

            else
            {
                System.out.println(srcc.getName());
                qu.addLast(srcc);
            }
        }

        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
        try {
            find(".php","C:\\AppServ");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

}
}
```

Comment: what isn't working? What is it outputting? More information, please.

Comment: yes i need find all document . php in my local i use iterative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anouar,

try to use [Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/io).
You can use class

```
org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils
```

described [here in API Javadoc](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/).

It provides very useful, performance-optimized and bug-free static methods to search files (listFiles and iterateFiles methods), copy/move files and directories, reading files to String in "one-line-of-code" and many more nice stuff.

There is no need to reinvent the wheel ;)

Answer (score 0):

You should try to not make a difference with the first folder / path and subfolders. What yoga are doing now is taking all files and folders from the src folder and adding them to the queue. Then you remove the first and check if it is a file. If it is, then if it matches the pattern you print it. If it is not a file, then you print the name and add it to the queue again!

Think about it. If your src folder contains one folder you take it from the queue, add it back and repeat until queue is empty (which it of course never will be).

You need something more like this

```
public static void find(String source,String rep) {
    String pattern = ".*"+source+"$";
    LinkedList<File> qu = new LinkedList<File>();
    File src = new File(rep);
    qu.add(src);
    while(!qu.isEmpty()) {
        File srcc = qu.removeFirst();

        if(srcc!=null && srcc.exists()) {
            if (srcc.isDirectory()) {
                File[] tab=srcc.listFiles();
                for(File s: srcc.listFiles()) {
                    qu.addLast(s);
                }
            } else if (srcc.isFile()) {
                if(srcc.getName().matches(pattern)) {
                    System.out.println(srcc.getName());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

where if the current file is a directory all subfiles are added to the queue and if it is a file the name is checked for match.